# Google Play Store rejects app updates but tests the wrong APK

Tags: android, google-play-console, android-security

We released the latest app version in July 2020. Google Play Console warned us about X509TrustManager vulnerability. We fixed that issue and uploaded an update to the 'Open testing' track. A new update was fine, the warning was gone. After that, on 12th October, they started to ban all apps with X509TrustManager vulnerability.

Now we are trying to submit a new release, but Google Play rejects it because of the X509TrustManager vulnerability. But notification letters about rejection always relate to the version presented in the 'Production' track since July, not to the one we've just uploaded.

In order to localize the problem, we've changed the app's bundle identifier and uploaded APK to Play Store as another application. And it was successfully accepted. So, it seems that there is no vulnerability in APK, but the Play Store tests the wrong APK for some crazy reason.

We also tried to replace APKs in all store tracks, but it didn't make any positive changes. We've already written to Google Play support about this problem but has never been answered.
Did someone face a similar issue?

[About X509TrustManager vulnerability](https://support.google.com/faqs/answer/6346016?hl=en)

[Letter from Google Play Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dto1O.png)

[Google Play Console info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W10cl.png)

Comment: welcome to stack overflow. i'm not sure what you're looking for as an answer here, as this is just a matter between yourself and google play store. people can share their own experience here and how it was eventually resolved, but at the end of the day it still has to be accepted by google play and that's a policy issue, not really a coding issue

Comment: Are you sure you fixed the policy related issue and uploaded new apk for the same app with same bundle ID for review?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. As I said, Google Play has already accepted fix, but after that started to reject the new ones.

Comment: Can you show the implementations of X509TrustManager in your project, maybe screenshot this from your IDE.

Comment: I don't have any implementations of X509TrustManager at all. Had one previously (in one obsolete library connected by Gradle), but got rid of it before app release.

Comment: @Pavel Loginov, from what you siad "In order to localize the problem, we've changed the app's bundle identifier and uploaded APK to Play Store as another application. And it was successfully accepted.", it looks like Play Console has some bug there. Did you ever contact Google guys to clarify that?